# Вопрос по Unit-тестам

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

Можно ли покрыть Unit-тестами значения полей. Если значения полей берутся(находятся) в БД.
?

Comment: А подробнее можно? Я лично ничего не понял. И зачем это нужно

Comment: а для чего это нужно? Юнит тестами обычно тестируют правильность работы логики программы

Comment: @KuzCode, есть textBox1 данные тянутся в него из базы данных. можно ли покрыть такие поля Unit-тестами?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, есть textBox1 данные тянутся в него из базы данных. можно ли покрыть такие поля Unit-тестами?

Comment: Надо проверять работу не заполнения полей, а логику работы приложения, как то "выбираются ли данные из БД в неком методе". И тогда если метод фейлит, тогда и поля никакие не заполнятся

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это сделать можно, но не нужно.

Юнит-тесты должны покрывать специфицированное *поведение* юнита. Поля же должны быть приватными, и являются деталью реализации.

Юнит-тесты трактуют тестируемый юнит как black box: что там внутри и как оно реализовано, юнит-тесту не важно, важно лишь то, какое поведение у юнита с точки зрения его (юнита) пользователей.